# Composition of two power series

Tags: power-series

I thought of this question:

$f, g$ are functions that could be written as a power series in a disc with radius $R>0$, i.e. $$\forall |x|<r, f(x)=\sum a_n x^n, g(x)=\sum b_n x^n$$. If $b_0 = 0$, do we always have that $f(g(x))$ could be written as a power series in a disc containing 0?

I can't prove or find a counterexample, could anyone give me a hand?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Is some complex analysis acceptable, or do you want a real-methods-only proof?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'd like to be in a complex plane :)

Comment: Then: the composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic; and a function is holomorphic if and only if it is (complex) analytic.

Comment: We can express the composition of $f (g (x)) $ as a *formal power series* when $b_0=0$, but this does not tell us the radius of convergence for the result.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I think I should reread my complex analysis, thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f (x) $ exists if $|x|<R $

$f (g (x)) $ exists if $|g (x)|<R $.

Since $g (0)=0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that

$g ((-\eta,\eta))\subset (-R,R) $.

thus $f (g (x)) $ exists for $|x|<\eta. $